# Byte of Python backup program is not working on Windows System

Tags: python-2.7

byte of python backup program is not working

The error I'm getting is zip command is not a recognized command on windows command prompt even after installing zip utility tool and setting the environment variables

This is the code:

```
import os
import time

source = ['"F:\PYTHON\byte of python code"']
target_dir = 'F:\\Backup'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.mkdir(target_dir) # make directory
zip_command = "zip -r {0} ".format(target,' '.join(source))
print "Zip command is:"
print zip_command
print "Running:"
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', target
else:
    print 'Backup FAILED'

raw_input("Press<Enter>")
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Zip command is:
zip -r F:\Backup\20170220120316.zip
Running:
'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Backup FAILED
Press<Enter>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: This code (to me) is all over the place. You're trying to use the Python commando `zip` in the Windows terminal? This could not be possible!

Comment: Looks like you don't have `zip` installed on your system, or it's not in your path.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. What does *"byte of python backup program"* mean? Also, please edit the question and state: (1) where is the program named `zip` located, and (2) what is your `$PATH` or `%PATH%` set to.